# Not Getting HTML TextBox Value in Javascript function? Have searched, but didn't find convincing answer

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm a beginner trying to get the HTML from a textbox to be used in an if/else statement.
This is my HTML code:

```
    <label id="label1">
    Enter any Number:
</label>
<input type="button" id="Button1"  value="button" />
    <input type="text" id="TextBox1" name="myname" />
```

And my JavaScript code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("Button1");
var txt_value =document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function() { Clicked(txt_value) }, false);

function Clicked(txt_value) {

    if (txt_value == 7) {
        alert("You are 7");
    }
    else { alert("You are not 7"); }
}
//]]>
    </script>
```

I observed that

```
    var txt_value =document.getElementById("TextBox1");
```

and then

```
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function() { Clicked(txt_value.value) }, false);
```

The above example works absolutely fine.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with:

```
    var txt_value =document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
```

I don't know why I'm getting an empty txt_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are getting the value in `txt_value` **before** the user enters anything; hence the value is always empty.

IF you change your code to this:

```
var txt_value =document.getElementById("TextBox1");//removed .value
```

And the function Clicked to:

```
function Clicked(txt_value) {

    if (txt_value.value == 7) { //added .value
        alert("You are 7");
    }
    else { alert("You are not 7"); }
}
```

Should work.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KHsG/)

Comment: thnks :) ya tht wrks i know. So Reason is m trying to access the value before user enters so getting empty nice thanku

Comment: @ShilpaGurnani I am glad I was able to help. I notice that you are knew here... please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most. This will increase the chances of getting help here in the future.

Comment: is that because of using addEventListener otherwise if m must have written onclick within html tag it must have wrked fine with var txt_value =document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;

Comment: ya sure :) i was accepting the answer but its like i got prompt that u can accept after 6 minutes

Comment: @ShilpaGurnani See my answer. I replaced the addEventHandler and made the code cleaner. Also made the comparison it more robust ;-)

Comment: @BartRiemens ya saw that thnks :) will follow hereafter

Comment: @ShilpaGurnani the problem is that your variable assignment (`var txt_value=document.getElementById('TextBox1').value`) occurs **immediately** when the page loads, before the user has a chance to interact with the page; hence the `txt_value` variable ends up being blank. You need to read the value only when the user clicks the button. It's okay to get a reference to the text input element when the page loads, but you need to read the value only when the user clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Move the getting of the value into the click handler...

```
var textbox1 = document.getElementById("TextBox1");

document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function () {
    var txt_value = textbox1.value;

    if (parseInt(txt_value, 10) === 7) {
        alert("You are 7");
    } else { 
        alert("You are not 7"); 
    }
};
```

Now you get the value that is in the textbox when the page loads.

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDjyG/)** to test this.

**Update** Improved the efficiency by caching the textbox. Removed the addEventListener to an onclick (more browser support)

Comment: Actually i read some where that latest is like use event listners instead of onclick hence used and btw i my addEventListener works for chrome and addEvent works for IE So Is ny other way which can be used across all browsers except the above onclick in tag?